# Why was this question seeking empirical evidence closed 'as primarily opinion-based'?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In [For long-term savings: Short-term Bond ETFs vs High-interest Savings Accounts](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48778/10763), I specifically asked for academic empirical evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the question has now been deleted by the Community user under the standard cleanup policies for old, closed questions.

It described competing strategies for investing in short-term bond ETFs versus high-interest savings accounts and ended by asking:

> But what do the empirical evidence and academic studies prove? Which is recommended?

"Primarily opinion-based" is often a judgement call - some questions do require some degree of subjective judgement to answer, but still aren't *primarily* opinion-based. However I think this question does fall on the wrong side of the line.

It's unlikely that there will be clear cut empirical evidence or academic studies that *prove* anything. In the end any answer will be someone's opinion about which is better, even if an informed, academic opinion.

Another possible problem with the question is that it's inviting a list of academic resources, and list questions are [discouraged on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/132930).

I think it might be possible to ask a question about this area and keep it on-topic, perhaps by asking a more direct question that focuses on concrete trade-offs rather than asking which is better. For example, someone commented on your question:

> Recommended for what? The two approaches trade different amounts of risk for different returns.

I think a question about the relative risks and returns of the two investments would be on-topic. The answers to such a question would be reasonably factual, rather than coming down to an explicit recommendation of one strategy over another.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive advice, because of which would you like to edit my OP?

Comment: I suggest you do the editing as you understand what you actually want to know. I've undeleted the question so other users can see it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just edited the OP. Better?

Comment: OK, I've cleaned it up a bit more and reopened it.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpfulness!